# Selenium, how to get element based on value?

Tags: python, selenium

The website i´m working with has 4 buttons of the same type that i need to distinguish. All of them have name="chooseMove" and then a value="1" from 1 to four.
How can I code 4 bouttons with find.element()?
All the other information including the text the button displays will change.

I´m working in python.

This is what the html element for one button looks like:
`<button class="type-Psychic has-tooltip" name="chooseMove" value="2" data-move="Zen Headbutt" data-target="normal" data-tooltip="move|Zen Headbutt|0">Zen Headbutt<br><small class="type">Psychic</small> <small class="pp">24/24</small>&nbsp;</button>`

All the information other than `name="chooseMove" value="2"` will change while the site is in use.
Website is play.pokemonshowdown.com, you'd have to get a game to get the move selection.

If I try `move1 = driver.find_element("name", 'chooseMove')`it will find the first of the four buttons.

Comment: you can use the xpath that should be unique. Please link the website

Comment: post your code and the html source page, it's not possible answer with just this information

Comment: ok I did update

Answer (score 0):

You have to use xpath like as below.

```
//input[@name='chooseMove' and @value='1']
```

Comment: thank you for your swift reply. python does not accept the @. if i try `find_element(name='chooseMove' and value=='1')` i get: NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Comment: for `find_element(name='chooseMove' and value='1')`I get syntaxError for `value=`

Comment: It's xpath, `find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='chooseMove' and @value='1']")`